# override fun toString() ignored on signed release apk

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit, android-databinding

I'm using databinding for spinner using android:entries, work only on debug but failed on release apk, override fun toString() become ignored

I'm using for(i in response.body) before bind, and it work, i'm just wondering if there is better solution and what is the problem causing this

```
<!--layout-->
<data>
    <import type="com.myproject.model.Group"/>
    <import type="java.util.List"/>
    <variable
        name="groups"
        type="List&lt;Group>"/>
</data>
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerGroup"
    android:entries="@{groups}"/>
```

code

```
//retrofit callback
override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Group>>, response: Response<List<Group>>) {
    for(i in response.body){} //temporary solution
    binding.groups=response.body
}

//model

class Group {

    @SerializedName("group")
    @Expose
    val group: String? = null

    override fun toString(): String {
        return group?:""
    }
}
```

expected entries on spinner

```
Group A
Group B
Group C
```

actual result

```
{group=Group A}
{group=Group B}
{group=Group C}
```

Comment: From my point of view, it will be better to just write `android:entries="@{group.group}` and don't use `toString` at all

Comment: @AndreiTanana correct me if i'm wrong, android:entries only receive array or list, and group.group is a string, care to explain?

Comment: I mean that instead of `binding.groups=response.body` I think you can write `binding.groups=response.body.map { it.group }` isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me this is related to **Proguard** configuration

I recommend to use **data** keyword at the begin of **Group** class and add **@Keep** annotation one line above of your class definition

```
@Keep
data class Group
```

another way to avoid this problem is adding a new rule into the Proguard file

```
-keep class com.myproject.model.Group.** { *; }
```

Comment: That's the problem, if one of my model not obfuscated, it will not pass penetration test